# why java String's getBytes method return different result?

Tags: java

I wrote a simple code:

```
public class Maintest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String key = "12345testabcd";
        System.out.println(key.getBytes());
        System.out.println(key.getBytes());
    }

}
```

when I run it the two print results are different.Why?Is this println related?Thx.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Comment: You aren't printing the contents of the byte array, you're printing the identity hash code, which is sort of like its memory location.

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing the default `toString` for each `byte[]` which is different each time as you get different byte[] instances back for each `key.getBytes()` call. Use this to see the contents of each byte array, they will have same values for same value of `key`:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(key.getBytes()));
```